# Validate DNA FASTA sequence using Javascript and RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex, fasta

I have a FASTA DNA Sequence. I want the text area to validate the fasta text for the below-given pattern. If the text does not follow the pattern then an error should be shown.

The pattern is that:
Each sequence will have a heading starting with the ">" symbol followed by alphanumeric and special characters.
Then in a new line, the text should only contain the letters from ["A","G","T","C"].

```
>sfr 354t:5
AGAAGTGAGTTTTGGATAGTAAAATAAGTTTCGAACTCTGGCACCTTTCAATTTTGTCGCACTCTCCTTG
TTTTTGACAATGCAATCATATGCTTCTGCTATGTTAAGCGTATTCAACAGCGATGATTACAGTCCAGCTG
TGCAAGAGAATATTCCCGCTCTCCGGAGAAGCTCTTCCTTCCTTTGCACTGAAAGCTGTAACTCTAAGTA
TCAGTGTGAAACGGGAGAAAACAGTAAAGGCAACGTCCAGGATAGAGTGAAGCGACCCATGAACGCATTC


>NC_000024.10:c2787682-2786855 Homo sapiens chromosome Y, GRCh38.p14 Primary Assembly
AGAAGTGAGTTTTGGATAGTAAAATAAGTTTCGAACTCTGGCACCTTTCAATTTTGTCGCACTCTCCTT
GTTTTTGACAATGCAATCATATGCTTCTGCTATGTTAAGCGTATTCAACAGCGATGATTACAGTCCAGC
TGTGCAAGAGAATATTCCCGCTCTCCGGAGAAGCTCTTCCTTCCTTTGCACTGAAAGCTGTAACTCTAA
GTATCAGTGTGAAACGGGAGAAAACAGTAAAGGCAACGTCCAGGATAGAGTGAAGCGACCCATGAACGC
ATTCATCGTGTGGTCTCGCGATCAGAGGCGCAAGATGGCTCTAGAGAATCCCAGAATGCGAAACTCAGA
GATCAGCAAGCAGCTGGGATACCAGTGGAAAATGCTTACTGAAGCCGAAAAATGGCCATTCTTCCAGGA
GGCACAGAAATTACAGGCCATGCACAGAGAGAAATACCCGAATTATAAGTATCGACCTCGTCGGAAGGC
```

This is what I tried:

```
("#fasta_text").on('change keyup paste', function(e) {
                            var seq = $(this).val();
                            if (!seq.match(/>+.*[a-z]+\n[AGCT]/igm))
                                e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use a pattern without any flags (or `/i` if you want to have a case insensitive match)

Note that you have these events `change keyup paste keypress` in the `.on` which may fire a lot of times and may in this case give a "No match for: " first.

```
const regex = /^[^\S\n]*>[^\s>].*(?:\n[^\S\n]*[AGTC]+)+$/;
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `[^\S\n]*` Match optional spaces
- `>[^\s>]` Match `>` followed by a non whitespace char other than `>`
- `.*` match the rest of the line
- `(?:` Non capture group to repeat as a whole part

  - `\n[^\S\n]*[AGTC]+` Match a newline, optional spaces and 1+ times any of `A` `G` `T` `C`
- `)+` Close the non capture group and repeat 1+ times
- `$` End of string

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XgPJfK/1)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  const regex = /^[^\S\n]*>[^\s>].*(?:\n[^\S\n]*[AGTC]+)+$/;
  $('#fasta_text').on('change keyup paste keypress', function(e) {
    const seq = $(this).val();
    if (!seq.match(regex)) {
      console.log("No match for: " + seq);
    } else {
      console.log("Match!")
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="fasta_text" rows="5" cols="80"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 2):

We can try using the following regex pattern:

```
\s*>\S+(?: \S+)*\s+[ACGT]+(?:\s+[ACGT]+)*
```

Sample script:

```js
var input = `    >sfr 354tfv
AGAAGTGAGTTTTGGATAGTAAAATAAGTTTCGAACTCTGGCACCTTTCAATTTTGTCGCACTCTCCTTG
TTTTTGACAATGCAATCATATGCTTCTGCTATGTTAAGCGTATTCAACAGCGATGATTACAGTCCAGCTG
TGCAAGAGAATATTCCCGCTCTCCGGAGAAGCTCTTCCTTCCTTTGCACTGAAAGCTGTAACTCTAAGTA
TCAGTGTGAAACGGGAGAAAACAGTAAAGGCAACGTCCAGGATAGAGTGAAGCGACCCATGAACGCATTC

>vkgi234 n.39
TAAGCGTATTCAACAGCGATGATTACAGTCCAGCTG
TGCAAGAGAATATTCCCGCTCTCCGGAGAAGCTCTTCCTTCCTTTGCACTGAAAGCTGTAACTCTAAGTA
TCAGTGTGAAACGGGAGAAAACAGTAAAGGCAACGTCCAGGATAGAGTGAAGCGACCCATGAACGCATTC`;

if (input.match(/\s*>\S+(?: \S+)*\s+[ACGT]+(?:\s+[ACGT]+)*/)) {
    console.log("MATCH");
}
```

Comment: Even if there is a character other than [ACGT] in the sequence, it still shows "match".